# How fix File 'xxx' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist

Tags: android, export, apk, build.gradle, signing

I'm new in android studio, when I want export the apk it give me error. This:

Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageRelease'.

> File 'sistemasmas' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.

How do I fix this error?

This is my build.gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sistemasmas.escribiramanowhatsapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}




buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'


    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the signing configuration to the build file for the `app` module

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("myreleasekey.keystore")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "MyReleaseKey"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

It will solve your problem. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the 'Generate Signed Apk' tool.
See your Android Studio's  Build ->  Generate Signed APK menu.

Otherwise,if you want package the project with command.You need define these in your release part.

```
 release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file('C://your-release-key.keystore')
    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = "yourstorePassword"
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = "yourkeyAlias"
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = "yourkeyPassword"
}
```

However,It's not safe to put your pass directly in build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me in the release{ section, but the following did

```
android {
signingConfigs {
    Signature {
        keyAlias 'yourfilealias'
        keyPassword 'yourkeypassword'
        storeFile file('keystore.jks')
        storePassword 'yourstorepassword.'
    }

} ...
```

Note: keystore.jks will probably need your path preceding it.